# Avro with Snappy Compression

Tags: c#, compression, hive, avro, azure-hdinsight

Any pointer to convert *.dat file to *.avro which compressed with Snappy in .NET Framework 4.5. I would like to make use of avro file in my Hive. Does hive support Avro format out of the box. should i need to mention serde for reading avro file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive does support Avro out of the box: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe

You can define Avro tables in Hive similarly to:

```
  CREATE TABLE kst
      PARTITIONED BY (ds string)
      ROW FORMAT SERDE
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
      STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
      OUTPUTFORMAT
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
      TBLPROPERTIES (
        'avro.schema.url'='http://schema_provider/kst.avsc');
```

Or as of Hive 0.14, similarly to:

```
CREATE TABLE kst (
    string1 string,
    string2 string
  )
  PARTITIONED BY (ds string)
  STORED AS AVRO;
```